# mat tab inside tab selected index not working

Tags: angular, angular-material2

When tab inside tab then if selected index of sub tab is 1 then it should show as selected.

Let parent tab has two tabs, it has `selectedIndex` is 0, and sub tab inside parent tab1 has `selectedIndex` = 1 then content inside it showing but is not showing as selected. Tab content is showing but tab is not selected

[image]

Here is the working **[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e3m6wb?file=app/tabs-overview-example.html)**

Answer (score 18):

There is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7274) for this. As a workaround you can use 2 way binding on your parent tab `selectedIndex` and then only show the subtab group when the parent tab is selected:

```
<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="index">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Parent tab 1 Content</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">
    <mat-tab-group *ngIf="index == 1" [selectedIndex]="1">
      <mat-tab label="Tab 1">sub tab 1 Content </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Tab 2">sub tab 2 Content
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e3m6wb-j9tbus)

Comment: thanks , for showing me that issue in github. +1 for your effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that worked for me was by setting on my .ts

```
parentTabSelected = false;     

handleMatTabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
        const index = localStorage.getItem('parentTab');
        if (event.index === Number(index)) {
            this.parentTabSelected = true;
        }
    }
```

then on my html file I called the function on the `<mat-tab-group>` element `(selectedTabChange)="handleMatTabChange($event)"` and by using on the `<mat-tab *ngIf="parentTabSelected">` it works.

Answer (score 0):

Set **selectedIndex** before the existence of the **MatTabGroup** and the contents of the selected tab will be displayed, also in this the contents will be visible correctly when **selectedIndexChange** and **selectedTabChange** fire.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the `selectedIndex` input doesn't always match the internal `tabIndex` in your component. That leads to a misaligned ink bar or the wrong tab content being shown.

Solution would be to set `this.matTabGroup.selectedIndex = this.tabIndex;`

```
tabIndex: number; // bound to [selectedIndex] of mat-tab-group
@ViewChild(MatTabGroup, { static: false }) private matTabGroup: MatTabGroup;

setGroupIndex(): void { // call this function whenever you change your tabIndex
    if (this.tabIndex !== this.matTabGroup.selectedIndex) {
        this.matTabGroup.selectedIndex = this.tabIndex; 
    }
}
```