# Angular material tab group problem on nested tab group (no default tab displayed)

Tags: angular, nested, angular-material

I'm facing the following problem with mat-tab-group nested inside a mat-tab-group. The nested group in the first tab of the parent group is selecting a default tab and showing the underline in the first tab, but the group nested in the third tab of the parent group, it's not showing the underline in any tab.

I've attached the link of the demo with the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tabs-problem

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47950958/mat-tab-inside-tab-selected-index-not-working?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mat tab inside tab selected index not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47950958/mat-tab-inside-tab-selected-index-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the [mat tab inside tab selected index not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47950958/mat-tab-inside-tab-selected-index-not-working?rq=1) question, the workaround provided there solved the problem.

Answer (score 15):

As this post suggests https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7274#issuecomment-605516292 wrap your child mat-tab-group with a `<ng-template matTabContent>` and it'll work (tested with Angular 8).

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Tab1">
    Test1
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab2" >
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab label="Tab2-1">
          Test2-1
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Tab2-2">
          Test2-2
        </mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Okay. This is better than other solutions out there.

Comment: This is a good work-around, however it causes the nested mat-tab-group to get lazed loaded instead of eagerly loaded!
https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading